# Is it possible to write short regex to replace function

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have function:

```
var replaceText = function(_findme, _replacement, _str) {

var result = '', i, sub, findmeLength, insideAmp = false;

if(!_str) {
    return '';
}

try {
    findmeLength = _findme.length;
} catch(ev) {
    findmeLength = 0;
}

if(findmeLength === 0) {
    return _str;
}

for(i=0;i<_str.length;i++) {
    sub = _str.substr(i, findmeLength);
    if(sub.toLowerCase() === _findme.toLowerCase() && !insideAmp) {
        result += _replacement||'';
        i += findmeLength-1;
    } else {
        result += _str[i];
    }
    if(_str[i] === '&') {
        insideAmp = true;
    }
    if(_str[i] === ';') {
        insideAmp = false;
    }
}

return result;
};
```

Is it possible to change it to some regular expression?

For example i want to run it with such data:

```
replaceText('lt', '<b>LT</b>', '&lt;h1&gt;text&lt;/h1&gt;Some text lt - linear technology');
```

Result should be:

```
&lt;h1&gt;text&lt;/h1&gt;Some text <b>LT</b> - linear technology
```

Basically i need some regex that would replace some characters in text without breaking html entities.

I need it for dynamic javascript highlight when user is searching something.

Comment: parsing HTML with regular expressions is not a popular way to go :) try googling it for reasons. Regular expressions can match regular languages, and HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: It would be better to give examples rather than providing the code

Comment: I really don't understand your example. You want to but `<b>` tags around `lt`, so you end up with `&<b>LT</b>;`? Why would you want that? There's probably a better way than a regex or that function, but your intent is unclear.

Comment: @MortenJensen Where did you see he's parsing HTML? HTML entities **are** regular (that would be something like `&#?\w+;`), and today's regexes aren't regular anymore. You can match entities with regexes without the slightest problem.

Comment: @squint I don't want to end up with &<b>LT</b>; - that's my problem. I have text with entities and I want to do replace on this text without breaking them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will do the trick:

```
replaceText = function(text, replacement, input) {
    // Escape regex metacharacters
    text = text.replace(/[-\\()\[\]{}^$*+.?|]/g, '\\$&');

    // Build the regex
    var re = new RegExp("&[^;]+;|\\b(" + text + ")\\b", "gi");

    // Do the replacement
    return input.replace(re, function(match, foundText) {
        return foundText ? replacement : match;
    });
};
```

Basically, either the regex matches an entity, and it doesn't replace it, or it matches your search string, and in that case it performs the substitution.

Your example gives the following result:

```
&lt;h1&gt;text&lt;/h1&gt;Some text <b>LT</b> - linear technology
```

Comment: This won't work for data like: "am", "<b>am</b>", "ammy is my girl" - it should return: "<b>am</b>my is my girl"

Comment: @Ascon Oh, I did this intentionally because I thought that's how it should work... Just remove both `\\b` and it will work like you expect it to.